# need help tweaking codeigniter friend query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

hello more knowledgeable horde.  very new here, trying to write a simple 'friends' query.  i have searched the SO base and couldn't divine the answer from the other questions/solutions.

i have two seemingly standard tables, one for membership with id/firstname/lastname etc, the other a friendship table with id/inviter_id/friend_id/status.  i have chosen (arbitrarily) to have friendship structured as one row per relationship rather than two rows per relationship.  (seems as though this problem would be easier / non-existent with two rows per, but feels like it would cause other problems and would like to solve it with one if possible.)

i am trying to return an array of firstname/lastname for all the people who are friends with the current user, and am mostly succeeding except i am also getting the user himself listed for each find, so 8 rows includes 4 of the current user e.g.  here is my codeigniter query:

```
$id = $this->session->userdata('id');
$this->db->select('first_name, last_name')->from("members");
$this->db->join('friendship', 'friendship.id_inviter = members.id OR friendship.id_friend = members.id');   
$where1 = "friendship.status = 'accepted' AND friendship.id_friend = $id";
$where2 = "friendship.status = 'accepted' AND friendship.id_inviter = $id";
$this->db->where($where1);
$this->db->or_where($where2);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query;
```

i imagine it's some elegant finesse i just can't see.  any thoughts?  thanks in advance.

Comment: Not familiar with codeigniter, but my guess would be you're getting the user theirself because you're allowing the query to work both ways (i.e. when the user is the friend and when the user is the inviter).  Try removing  "OR friendship.id_friend = members.id".  If that works you can also get rid of where1 and just rename where2 to where1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `"members.id != $id"` to your where clause.

Comment: perfect, thx man. seems so obvious in retrospect but such is genius. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
$this->db->select('members.first_name, members.last_name')->from("friendship");
$this->db->join('members', 'members.id = friendship.friend_id');
$this->db->where('friendship.inviter_id',$id);  
$this->db->get();
```

Comment: thanks much for taking the time on this, but the above solution did the trick, and i'm having trouble with this one... thx for the thinking tho.